# why Spring tool suite IDE shows error message as "JVM terminated. Exit code=127"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I tried to install spring-tool-suite 4.1(64  bit) on Cent OS-7, when i try to run installer, it shows message like "JVM terminated. Exit code=127"

I have a latest 16.0.2(64 bit) JDK version,
Edited the .ini file with correct jdk path, but still it shows the same error message

I faced the same problem while using eclipse installer also, tried the  given solutions in stack overflow, none of them worked

[image]

This is the version I am using:

```
java -version
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: May be that Eclipse version is not compatible with Java 16

Comment: Even i tried with JDK 11 version, getting the same error message

Comment: @LMC That's not the case. The current Eclipse version (which is used here) is even shipped with a Java 16 VM.

Comment: Better use the Java that comes with Eclipse instead of using the Java installed on your system. Maybe your Java is 32 bit causing this. `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java -version` would tell us more.

Comment: @howlger i'm using 64 bit only, i edited the question, please check once

Comment: @howlger, i checked with the default version of eclipse, it was plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.linux.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205/jre/bin, 
this also shows the same error message, then only i edit .ini file and gave my system path

Comment: The `...minimal.stripped...` is the wrong one, you need the full one, with the full system library to run the Eclipse IDE. The fact that it is offered to you as an option indicates that you are using an outdated Eclipse Installer. Alternatively, you can download an [IDE package as a ZIP](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) containing the right Java.

Comment: @howlger ok, the plugin which i mentioned above was found in eclipse installer.ini, 
but in sts intsaller.ini, i found this plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/bin

Comment: The `...minimal.stripped...` is included in and enough to run the Eclipse Installer, but not the Eclipse IDE. In the past, for a short time, the Eclipse Installer offered it as an option. `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)` looks good. Are you sure this is the `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.2/bin/java` one?

Comment: yes, that path is correct

Comment: I tried installing from the above given link,
it gives me the same error message,
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/home/hduser/Pictures/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205/jre/bin/java

Comment: It's a `x86_64` machine, not Arm, right? Which GTK version do you have?

Comment: My Centos version : centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
Gtk version : gtk2-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64

Comment: [Eclipse requires GTK 3.20 or higher](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version)

Comment: yes, this solution worked for me, i updated gtk version to 3.22, sts and eclipse, both are working now, Thank you so much

Comment: Great that it works now. I added it as an answer.

Comment: ok, will gtk update effect any other existing process?

Comment: Removing GTK 2.x might cause issues in old applications, but as far as I know you can have both GTK 2.x and GTK 3.x installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure

- using a **64 bit Java VM of the same architecture** to run Eclipse (in your case x86_64) and
- on Linux having [**GTK 3.20 or higher**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version).